# MySQL search by json-column intersection

Tags: mysql

MySQL 5.7.22

I've got a table named `products` with a json column `shipping_method_ids`
I'd like to select all products which match at least one shipping_method_id, how would i do that?

At the moment, i've got the following things:

```
mysql> DESCRIBE products;
+----------------------+---------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field                | Type          | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+----------------------+---------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| shipping_method_ids  | json          | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+----------------------+---------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+


SELECT * FROM products WHERE(JSON_CONTAINS products.shipping_method_ids, [1, 2, 3])
```

As a result, i'd like to get all products which match at least one shipping_method_id but i don't know what to use as a condition e.g.

```
mysql> SELECT id, shipping_method_ids FROM products WHERE (...);
+----+---------------------+
| id | shipping_method_ids |
+----+---------------------+
|  1 | [1, 2, 3]           |
|  2 | [1]                 |
|  3 | [2, 3]              |
+----+---------------------+
```

How can i select all products by a present intersection of the given array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I thinks this will work

```
SELECT * 
FROM products 
WHERE 
  JSON_CONTAINS(shipping_method_ids,'1') OR
  JSON_CONTAINS(shipping_method_ids,'2') OR
  JSON_CONTAINS(shipping_method_ids,'3')
```

or you can use regexp

```
SELECT * FROM products WHERE shipping_method_ids REGEXP '[1-3]'
```

Comment: This works, but is there a way without joining multiple conditions? Is there a way to use JSON_CONTAINS with an array argument as second parameter? or is JSON_SEARCH the way to go? If so, how would i use it the correct way?

Comment: You can use regexp in this case SELECT * FROM products WHERE shipping_method_ids REGEXP '[1-3]'

Comment: Okay, didn't know about that one! it really does work and i am amazed. However, if i've got a product with a shipping_method_id 10, it would match the regular expression which i do not want.I couldn't find word boundaries for mysql regexp, thus i came up with the following solution `select shipping_method_ids from products where shipping_method_ids REGEXP '[^0-9][1][^0-9]'` where the middle capture group are the ids

Comment: Regex is a power, but you should use it wisely. I would also recommend regex tester like this https://regex101.com/

Comment: Do you know if JSON_SEARCH would be an option to get to the requested result?

Comment: No, it returns path where expression can be found, not string which satisfies condition